# Accessing non-existent property 'connect' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting this warning while running a node.js and mysql project on server.
bcrypt,dotenv,express,joi,jsonwebtoken,mysql,mysql2 these are the dependencies that I use. In the code i have not used "connect" anywhere but it is getting exported into files where I am using database connection.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.